# error when installing python parsley

Tags: python, installation, parsley

I'm trying to install parsley, a parser written in python, but I'm stuck at the first hurdle. I can't even install it.
I'm on windows 7, using cygwin.

And this version of python:
$ python3 -V
Python 3.4.2

```
$ pip install Parsley
Downloading/unpacking Parsley
  Running setup.py (path:C:\cygwin64\tmp\pip_build_ds\Parsley\setup.py) egg_info for package Parsley

Installing collected packages: Parsley
  Running setup.py install for Parsley
      File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\ometa\interp.py", line 252
        except ParseError, err:
                         ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

      File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\ometa\runtime.py", line 484
        except ParseError, e:
                         ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

      File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\ometa\test\test_pymeta.py", line 101
        self.assertEqual(g.stuff([17, 0x1f, -2, 0177]), 0177)
                                                   ^
    SyntaxError: invalid token

      File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\ometa\vm_builder.py", line 7
        print "Gonna compile", expr
                            ^
    SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'

      File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\parsley.py", line 86
        except ParseError, e:
                         ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

      File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\terml\test\test_terml.py", line 40
        Term(Tag('.int.'), 0755, None, None))
                              ^
    SyntaxError: invalid token

Successfully installed Parsley
Cleaning up...
```

Then in python's IDLE:

```
>>> import parsley
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    import parsley
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\parsley.py", line 86
    except ParseError, e:
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

[`Parsley`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Parsley/1.2) (1.2 for now) does not support Python 3.x.

You need to use Python 2.x to use the package.

Comment: The latest version on Github looks like it supports Python 3.x
You could try to install that one instead of the pypi-version.

https://github.com/python-parsley/parsley